# Connecting to a wifi network using python

Tags: python, wifi

I have this code that is supposed to connect to wifi using a given ESSID and password. Here is the code:

```
def wifi_connect(essid, password):
# Connect to the wifi. Based on the example in the micropython
# documentation.
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
if not wlan.isconnected():
    print('connecting to network ' + essid + '...')
    wlan.connect(essid, password)
    # connect() appears to be async - waiting for it to complete
    while not wlan.isconnected():
        print('waiting for connection...')
        print('checking connection...')
    print('Wifi connect successful, network config: %s' % repr(wlan.ifconfig()))
else:
    # Note that connection info is stored in non-volatile memory. If
    # you are connected to the wrong network, do an explicity disconnect()
    # and then reconnect.
    print('Wifi already connected, network config: %s' % repr(wlan.ifconfig()))
```

At first, I got an error message that network was not installed. This was fixed by simply using pip to install network. After I ran this again, it told me that network has no attribute WLAN. How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run code designed for the [MicroPython language](http://micropython.org/), and it won't work on CPython (the Python version you'd download from Python.org or find installed on most PCs and servers).

MicroPython is designed to run on embeddable specialist hardware, and comes with its own library to support the hardware it is running on, including a [`network` module](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/network.html):

> To use this module, a MicroPython variant/build with network capabilities must be installed. Network drivers for specific hardware are available within this module and are used to configure hardware network interface(s).

It tells you so in the comments at the top:

```
# [...] Based on the example in the micropython
# documentation.
```

The code can't run on 'regular' CPython. You installed the [PyPI `network` project](https://pypi.org/project/network/), which is a very different module, [originally designed to help learn coding for the Raspberry PI](https://github.com/raspberrypilearning/networking-lessons).

What project *could* work depends on your operating system (OS). Different OSes use different programming interfaces to let programs change networks. Most have *command line tools* to let you do this, which should be easy to drive from Python with the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

- Windows has the [`netsh` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh), run [`netsh wlan connect name=...`](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx) to connect to a network interface
- Mac OS X has the [`networksetup` command](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/networksetup/), `networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 ...` connects you to a given WIFI network.

Comment: Thanks! I have installed micropython with homebrew. One thing... what is a GUI I can use to create micropython files?

Comment: @c0mraide: do you actually have a MicroPython-compatible piece of hardware? You can't use MicroPython to control your Mac network connection...

Comment: Sorry... I am a bit confused. If the network module in micropython can't control my computer's connection to wifi networks, does that code even work? And how can I tell if my hardware is compatible?

Comment: The language is meant to control *specialised, very compact hardware*.  A bit like a Raspberry Pi but smaller. The MicroPython site lists what specific hardware is compatible. If you have a PC that runs Linux or Windows or Mac OS X then that will *not* be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

On a PC, you don't need network.py to connect to a Wifi access point as in ESPP32.
You connect normally by OS network connection.

The only library you need is socket. Here an example of code to get data !

```
import socket
def http_get(url, port):
    _, _, host, path = url.split('/', 3)
    addr = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)[0][-1]
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(addr)
    s.send(bytes('GET /%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n' % (path, host), 'utf8'))
    while True:
        data = s.recv(100)
        if data:
            print(str(data, 'utf8'), end='')
        else:
            break
    s.close()

http_get('http://micropython.org/ks/test.html',80)
http_get('http://towel.blinkenlights.nl/',23)
```